# Can't sign app in Android Studio (no way to choose signatures)

Tags: android, google-play, android-signing

This happens after hitting next twice:
[image: enter image, description here]

In my opinion the above shouldn't be possible. I think clicking next doesn't update the UI and doesn't show the next dialog with the signature type selection.
Am I missing something?

Android 3.2 Canary 12

Answer (score 0):

This is known as a bug in the Canary 12 version.